# how to undo replaced code in java NetBens

Tags: java

By mistake I replaced String to setString in JAVA NetBeans and all 715 word replaced, how I undo this.
I tried to use Control + Z but no result.
please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recover the old files which you modified from the local history in netbeans.
You can check like project **tree -> context menu - >Local History**.
For more details you can check this [link](https://ui.netbeans.org/docs/ui/LocalHistory/).